# Docker Postgres - error while creating a database and user

Tags: postgresql, docker

I use the official Postgres image from the Docker Hub

```
docker pull postgres
```

I start my container in my machine on local:

```
docker run --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_USER=user -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -e POSTGRES_DB=test postgres
```

The container would have to create my `test` base with my `user` on port `542`

I have this error when I want to connect on my `db`

```
$ sudo docker run -it postgres /bin/bash
root@ef4407c26a96:/# su postgres
postgres@ef4407c26a96:/$ psql
psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
postgres@ef4407c26a96:/$
```

Comment: not able to reproduce the issue. I get a different error: `psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist`

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the database that you want to connect to. As you've provided `POSTGRES_DB=test`, use it when you wish to connect to psql:

```
psql -d test -U user
```

Also, I was able to connect with `psql` both as `root` and `postgres` user.